# How to "find by element" using React Testing Library

Tags: react-testing-library

I am new to this react testing library, but I would like to do something very simple, basically find HTML elements.

```
expect(screen.findByElemnet("div")).toHaveLength(5);
```

I can achieve this wonderfully in Enzyme, but nothing in the API for react testing library indicates that I can do this. All the `find` and `get` functions seem to deal with things like "roles" and "labels". I can't use these in the code I am testing.

I am using the screen module, because I assume that is the container where I do all my querying from?

Comment: That's not possible in RTL, you should follow the recommended [queries priority](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#priority) when trying to access elements. If none of them fits your use case, then as a last resort you could add a test ID to the element and use `getByTestId` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing goes against the project's [guiding principles](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles/):

> We try to only expose methods and utilities that encourage you to write tests that closely resemble how your web pages are used.

This is the reason queries are done by labels, roles, accessible names, text, etc.  These things are part of the user experience in a way that is meaningful to a user.  For example, a user could be directed to click the 'save' button (`screen.getByRole('button', { name: /save/i })`), but they can't be directed using implementation details, which can change without affecting the user experience.

The closest you'll get to an escape hatch from these principles is by using `data-testid` (see: [ByTestId](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid)), which is mostly a last resort option for finding specific elements that need to be tested but cannot be reliably found by text, label, role, etc.